# How to input to differant multiple lists using one loop in pthon

Tags: python, list, loops, input

Hi im kinda new to python and i have a question that i cant find any answer for that.

ok, imagine we have 5 students and we want to take their scores in 3 lessons (e.g., math, science, geography) and we have empty lists named by these lessons, i want to know how can we input their scores in this lists using one loop and not by writing the code one by one for this lists.
scores inputs be like

```
80 90 95 40 70
70 50 60 50 50
80 90 90 80 80
```

thes are our lists:

```
    math = science = geography =[]
```

and i know how to input multiple variables:

```
[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

i tried to use 'for' like below but it doesnt work cause it gives 'i' equal amount of lists but does not copy the results to list.

```
i = []
for i in math, science, geography:
        i = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

so please help me if you can, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should try exploring Dictionary in Python. It would be more suitable for this use case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2 problems:

1.
`math = science = geography = []` - this will assign **the same reference** to all the variables. Which means every change you do on one of the lists will be reflected in other ones.

2.

```
for i in math, science, geography:
        i = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Here you are changing the reference `i` points to when you assign new list to it, thus making it no longer the same thing each of `math, science, geography` are.
You need to edit each of the given lists **in-place**.
With those two things in mind, if you rewrite your code like so, it will work:

```
math = []
science = []
geography = []
for i in math, science, geography:
        i.extend([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d ={}
for i in ['math', 'science', 'geography']:
        d[i] = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

You can simply store it in a dictionary where the dictionary keys are the subjects and the items are lists containings marks obtained by students.

```
{'math': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'science': [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 'geography': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

*OR*

If you have 3 separate lists prepared and want to populate those, you can simply do this

```
subject_lists = []
for i in ['math', 'science', 'geography']:
        subject_lists.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

Now `subject_lists` contains all the lists in order. If you have some order specified somewhere that first list is for subject 1 and second for subject 2 you can use it easily.

```
   subject_map = {
     'math':0,
     'science':1,
     'geo':2
   }
```

So now if you have to access the subject `math` to get the scores achieved by students, you can simply think like this

```
subject_index = subject_map['math']
math_scores = subject_lists[subject_index ]
```

Comment: sure this is a good way but i want to copy the results in prepared empty lists, my question is just an example to find this possible function. thanks btw

Comment: @MohsenSalimi Check the answer.

Comment: It's not really clear how one would make `specific_list` point to the same list as e.g. `math` based on the `'math'` string alone from your answer.

Comment: @matszwecja That's basically can be done in lots of ways and is not the major detail I thought. Since the major part the OP was missing is the update of the list. One way would be to simply enumerate the list and process from there or just iterate over the list refs

Comment: i believe in this way inputs append to specific_list ! i don't know if i understand the second part of your answer or not but i want scores to append to math , geo and science list and i dont want to write these 3 times....imagine if they were 100 lists!

Comment: @MohsenSalimi Check the answer now. This would return list of list and you dont need to hardcode anything

Comment: @matszwecja Check the answer. I have made things clear a bit. Thanks for earlier feedback.

Comment: @user2736738 overly complicated, but works now so downvote removed.

Comment: @matszwecja Just imagine, if there are 10-25 subjects, in your solution they would have to write 20 assignment of lists. In this case, once you have the dictionary thats it. (You can have such dics from databases easily).  *Btw, I didn't DV your solution (just to be clear)*. Surprisingly Op likes your solution but it is exactly same as my earlier solution.... strange SO behaviors.

Comment: @user2736738 I agree that dictionary would probably be better, but OP said that he needs to put the results in "in prepared empty lists", thus I kept to that requirement.